# PHP stripslashes eating too many backslashes

Tags: php, stripslashes

I'm trying to strip some slashes with the traditional `stripslashes` function and am getting odd results:

```
echo stripslashes('\\\\');
```

This gives me: `\`

```
echo stripslashes('\\\\\\\\\\\\');
// there should be 12 slashes above
```

This gives me: `\\\` (there should be three slashes here. Even SO is being weird with it)

It's eating double the slashes >.<

However when I plug the same input to http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/stripslashes/ the result comes out fine?

Anyone know what's going on? How can I control stripslashes' appetite and make it stop double gobbling these sloshes?

Comment: php will escape double backslash in a single quote

Comment: I see what you mean about SO being weird about it.

Comment: @leftclickben Yeah. It is real hard to type a lot of backslashes in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backslash `\` escapes one character following it. In order to print a backslash, you need two:

```
\\
```

`\\\\` gives you two backslashes since each backslash escapes the one following it.

`stripslashes('\\\\');` strips one backslash from the remaining two.

Comment: you should explain about single and double quote too

Comment: Actually, a backslash in a single quote escapes only a following single quote (`\'`) or another backslash (`\\ `).  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: The thing is, I'm only getting one backslash. I'm expecting to get two, but somehow my php is idk.. double stripping it and leaving me with one backslash instead of two

Comment: @2unco You have 4 backslashes which gives you 2 after escaping. Further striping gives you one.

Comment: @2unco Try `echo '\\\\';` and you will see 2 backslashes you're expecting.

Comment: @Anthony I guess I'll elaborate on my problem. I'm taking user input from AJAX; without stripslashes I'm getting backslashes behind quotes - with stripslashes I'm losing too many backslashes. A bit confusing :/

Comment: @2unco Don't just call `stripslashes` on every backslash you see. If they are there for a reason, leave them there. Otherwise, you can count the number of continuous backslashes and take half of that number as the expected outcome. From there you can determine if further striping is necessary.

Comment: @2unco Can you give me an example of "I'm getting backslashes behind quotes"? I am confused as well.

Comment: @Anthony I'm going to refactor and see if the problem persists. Sorry :( I'm a bit confused